# Unit Testing - test for file count and folder size

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I have homework JS code to check every week.
I have tests for JS logic, but i also has a requirement for overall size and file quantity. 
So i was wondering is there any possibility to write tests (i assume mocha - because it runs on node, and has access to FS) for folder size and file count in folder (also has a limit)?

I have no experience in Mocha or Node, so should i dive deeper?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure what you are asking, but:

Mocha is a framework to run "unit tests" to test the software you have written and see if it's working ok.

If you just want to count some files in a directory you don't need a testing framework. Just use node's normal filesystem classes in `fs` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that files maybe you are talking about integration test and not unit test. So, I believe that if you want to make unit test you will need read something about mock's and stub's. You can search modules like sinon. A few weeks I was fighting with test that checks if dirs or files are created and I reached the conclusion that if I want to make unit tests I need that module. [Here's Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/)